# How to populate data from a dataset or datatable into a report table using telerik reporting?

Tags: datatable, telerik, dataset, reporting

How to populate data from a dataset or datatable into a report table using telerik reporting?

I've been trying to so by binding an objectdatasource to a datatable next I bind the object to the report table but it cant acces the default GetData() method neither display the data fields.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: And it's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context.
Do you want a answer from Code Behind or GUI? Witch designer are you using : VS, Standalone?  Have you read the  [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/data-items-binding-a-data-item-to-data) about it.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to achieve a simple databinding it's to use the GUI.

#### You're a wizard Miguel!

1. Open your Report in design mode.
2. Click the Data Source Components.
   *Let the Magic happen follow the wizard.*
3. Add Your Data Item ( Report / Table / List ...)
4. Click, Rigth Click > Properties, Data: Datasource

You will be designing your report mainly by the GUI. Play a bit with it to learn.